# Rails Log are not getting writtento file after manually editing file on ubuntu server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, logging, server

I have general.log file in application, I edited file on server manually using vi (without sudo) for some reason and saved file using `esc + : + wq`

After this logs are not getting written to the general.log

I have checked the permission before and after the edit, its the same

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 42K Jan 31 08:32 general.log
```

Anyone know what may be the issue?

Issue resolved by deployment but I'm investigating the cause.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here - you would expect Rails to write to `log/{environment}.log` where environment is typically one of test, development or production. Why would you expect Rails to write to that file?

Comment: @max I have custom logger class to write log to that file